# How to apply interfaces and abstraction in PHP

Tags: php, oop, interface

So I have understood how interfaces and abstraction work in PHP, I just don't see the point for example, of having a interface if it just sets a guide and requires implemented objects to have certain methods. Especially since the interface is not even getting instantiated.

This also goes with abstraction, I just can't apply it to my code and see it as such a great thing. When I am trying to create objects on a bigger scale to interact with each other in order to figure out interfaces, each class ends up passing information back and forth, but never is the interface touched.

So what I'm asking is if you guys have any advice or links to outside sources that is good at explaining this kind of thing.

Comment: For ex. take one of frameworks like "Zend framework" and try understand how one of his components works, and you will get real world example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple example. Creating interfaces and abstract classes allows you to ensure an object adhears to a common API. See the example below.

```
interface iCar
{
    function drive();
}

abstract class Car implements iCar
{
    public $make = 'Generic';

    public function drive()
    {
        printf("I'm driving in my %s%s", $this->make, PHP_EOL);
    }
}

class FordTruck extends Car
{
    public $make = "Ford";
}

class Porsche extends Car
{
    public $make = 'Porsche';
    public function drive()
    {
        printf("I'm speeding around in my %s%s", $this->make, PHP_EOL);
    }
}

class Yugo extends Car
{
    public $make = 'Yugo';

    public function drive()
    {
        printf("I'm pushing my %s around town%s", $this->make, PHP_EOL);
    }
}

function drive(iCar $car)
{
    $car->drive();
}

$car1 = new FordTruck;
$car2 = new Porsche;
$car3 = new Yugo;


drive($car1);
drive($car2);
drive($car3);
```

Even if you don't specify the type of input parameter on the `drive()` function, you can check if the input is an `instanceof` an iCar

```
function drive($car)
{
    if ($car instanceof iCar)
        $car->drive();
}
```

Another example would be building a caching interface in your application. You can specify that all cache engines support the same methods for reading/writing/invalidating objects in the cache without knowing (or caring) about the actual implementation of a particular cache engine.

Comment: What will happen if you simply use `class Car implements iCar` instead of `abstract class Car implements iCar` ?

Answer (score 0):

I could give you the simplest as possible example.

Assume you want a feature that allow your site to login with Facebook/Twitter

```
# here's your interface/abstract class
interface Auth_Adapter {
    public function auth();
}

# now your Facebook
class Auth_Adapter_Facebook implements Auth_Adapter {
    public function login() {
        # include facebook-sdk and auth
    }
}

# Twitter
class Auth_Adapter_Twitter implements Auth_Adapter {
    public function login() {
        # include twitter-oauth and auth
    }
}
```

Imagine when someone try to use Facebook/Twitter thing They can simply call

```
$adapter = new Auth_Adapter_Facebook; 
$adapter->login();

$adapter = new Auth_Adapter_Twitter; 
$adapter->login();
```

As you can see both adapters use the same `login` interface. What's happen if in the future you have to include 'Pinterest' login? Your code still work as long as you implement the same interface.

**EDIT:** More explanations

Here's the reason why you have to use `interface or abstract`

```
# I use `type-hinting` here. So I can ensure that only object that implements `Auth_Adapter` will allow. Without this implementation someone might pass some other object that doesn't have `login` method in. But in our case we don't have to worry about that.
public function perform_login(Auth_Adapter $adapter) {

    $adapter->login();
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but couldnt you just take out `implements Auth_Adapter` and it would do the exact same thing?